# Is Comparator only used with SortedSet or can it be used with other interfaces in Collection?

Tags: java

Can anyone explain with example. The examples I have seen so far included just SortedSet(using TreeSet for implementation) and List (using ArrayList for implementation). I want to know whether we can work with set, map... if so how?

Comment: Have you considered consulting the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/class-use/Comparator.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is used in other classes! For example, the `Arrays` class has a `sort` method that accepts a `Comparator` as an argument. Here is the docs:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20int,%20int,%20java.util.Comparator)

Actually, for this kind of stuff you can search online and you can see the methods that accept `Comparator` as an argument. I think most collection classes have that.

You also asked how to use comparators with sets and maps. And the answer is... (drum roll) in the docs! Just google search it and you will find the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Comparators are used in many places in the Java API.

As an example, the `Stream` class uses `Comparator` in the `min` and `max` methods to return the minimum or maximum item in a stream according to a give comparator.

For example:

```
interface Person {
    int getAge();
}

List<Person> people;
Optional<Person> oldestPerson = people.stream()
    .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge));
```

An example of finding a map key using a comparator on the key's value:

```
Map<String, Integer> employeeNameSalaryMap;
Optional<String> lowestPaidPerson = employeeNameSalaryMap
    .valueSet().stream()
    .min(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey);
```

Comment: Can you explain with a map like Employee class <key,value> ~ <id,name>.

Comment: @Delfin sure will add a map example